# How do I append to each item in a list of strings?

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I have a list of strings containing IP addresses. I want to append a port number to each of them. In python I would do it something like this:

```
ip_list = [(ip + ":" + port) for ip in ip_list]
```

...but Jinja doesn't support list comprehensions. At the moment I'm kludging the problem by building a new list one item at a time:

```
{%- set ip_list = magic() %}
{%- set new_ip_list = [] %}
{%- for ip in ip_list %}
  {%- do new_ip_list.append(ip + ":" + port) %}
{%- endfor %}
```

This is ugly and irritating in the middle of a template, and it feels like there should really be a better way to get the job done. Preferably a one-liner.

While I know this can be done with custom filters, I'm supplying a template to software I did not write (saltstack), so they are (as far as I know) unavailable to me.

Comment: Check out [this blog post](https://www.itix.fr/blog/ansible-add-prefix-suffix-to-list/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`regex_replace` can do this. It is available in [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-text) and [saltstack](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#regex-replace):

```
magic() | map('regex_replace', '$', ':'~port) | list
```

- map: apply the `regex_replace` filter to each list element (like `listElement | regex_replace('$', ':'~port)`)
- replace: replace end of string with `:` and port (so append it)
- list: convert generator to list

Using a regexp is overkill, but my other tries were even more so. Unfortunately `regex_replace` [does not exist in normal jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#builtin-filters).

Comment: [Saltstack has the same `regex_replace` filter](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#regex-replace) as Ansible.

Comment: Returning to the problem quite a while later, this is the least-aggravating method I'm aware of. I edited the post to include the link 200 mentioned (hope the author doesn't mind) and marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The way I've been doing it is using `zip_longest` to create lists in the list of strings then joining them.

`ip_string_list | zip_longest([], fillvalue='some_port') | map('join') | list`

of course if you have the port in a variable you can do:

`ip_string_list | zip_longest([], fillvalue=port_string) | map('join') | list`

You can include a separator in the `join` operation too:

`ip_string_list | zip_longest([], fillvalue=port_string) | map('join', ':') | list`

To prepend throw in a `reverse`:

`ip_string_list | zip_longest([], fillvalue=port_string) | map('reverse') | map('join', ':') | list`

I use this pattern all the time for building LDAP distinguished names.

Edit: This is how I do it in Ansible, `zip_longest` isn't in stock Jinja2

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means pretty, but this worked for me. I needed to build a list of usernames with a "!" in front of each one. This list has to be placed on a line with commas between the users.

My list of users (set in vars, defaults or whatever) looks like:

```
excluded_users: ["fred","jim","bob","arthur"]
```

In my template I've got this:

```
Match user *,!root{% if excluded_users|length > 0 %},!{{ excluded_users|join(",!") }}{% endif %}
```

...once rendered and saved, it looks like this:

```
Match user *,!root,!fred,!jim,!bob,!arthur
```

Like I said, not particularly pretty ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Not having list comprehensions in ANY language is annoying!

Could you use the "|format" filter?

```
{% for ip in magic() -%}
curl_host_port:
  cmd.run:
    - name: {{ "curl 'http://%s:80/'"|format(ip) }}
{% endfor -%}
```

Comment: Sadly, no. I need the result to be a list of jinja string objects (it gets passed through join() later).

Answer (score 0):

just iterate on the list item ans use jinja2 to print element like this:

```
   - set_fact:
        list_ip: "{% for ip in ip_list %}{{ip}}:{{port}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
```

And the lisp_ip vars will have your string ip:port separate with commas. And you can then split it to obtains a list

> lisp_ip.split(',')